# How to know the name of the background image used at home screen android?

Tags: android, android-widget

How I can know the name of the image used in android home screen?

I use [WallpaperInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperInfo()) But it is not giving me name of wallpaper.

Comment: Have You tried anything? post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot. When the wallpaper is set, the `WallpaperManager` is just given a Bitmap.. So it does not know anything about the original data that was used to set it.

No filename is ever transferred to the `WallpaperManager`, just the actual data to display..

Comment: In such a case I have to know a way for comparing bitmap.

Comment: Then you should check out the `sameAs()` function for Bitmaps [Android Reference for Bitmap.sameAs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)